# vbs runs by double clicking, freezes when run from task scheduler

Tags: vbscript, task, scheduler

I have a .vbs script that copies files from multiple remote computers. Each server has a shared folder that I map as a network drive (W:). When I run it by double-clicking, it runs fine, but if I run it from Task Scheduler (Win Server 2003) it hangs on this line:

NetworkObject.MapNetworkDrive "W:", "\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\sharename", false, [username], [password]

I've tried everything but I can't figure out why it won't run in task scheduler. Please help!

Comment: What user context does the scheduled task run in? Can you start a command prompt as that user (via `runas`) and manually run the script in that user's context?

Comment: As @Ansgar Wiechers points out, the account in your Task may be locked out or not sufficient rights. Can you get the info Ansgar is looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to run it like:

```
C:\Windows\system32\cscript.exe yourscript.vbs
```